# telnet with python - no prompt after password input

Tags: python, telnet

I'm trying to telnet to a Netgear switch through a Python script.
I succeed to connect through Putty, but when I'm trying with Python code
I get nothing (no prompt) after putting the password (which is empty, only need to press enter.

Here is the code:

```
import getpass
import telnetlib
import time

HOST = "10.10.10.1"
user = input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until(b"User: ")
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

tn.write(b"ls\n")
tn.write(b"exit\n")

print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
```

I tried to put sleep delays and double checked the `read_until` parameters and also with and without spaces, but with no success.

Comment: Can anyone support? i searched all previous questions here but none of them are related to login fail

Comment: i'm using python3, maybe it is related to the read_until lines? i double checked in case of case sensitive identification.

Answer (score 0):

Use tn.expect instead of tn.read_until